# How to retrieve request URI in Apache virtual host configuration file on Redhat?

Tags: apache, load-balancing, redhat, httpd.conf

I have created a Httpd Virtual host configuration file under `/etc/httpd/conf.d` to load balance between 2 servers. My configuration looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost  *:8086>
        ProxyRequests off
        ServerName  domain.com
        <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
                BalancerMember http://example1.com/b
                BalancerMember http://example2.com/b
                Allow from all
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        </Proxy>

        <Location /balancer-manager>
                SetHandler balancer-manager
        </Location>

        ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
        ProxyPass /a/b balancer://mycluster/

</VirtualHost>
```

If you see the above configuration, I am accessing my load balancer at the URL, `domain.com:8086/a/b`. My requirement is that when the request comes as `domain.com:8086/a/b/c/d` where c,d are dynamic values, I want to append them to my BalancerMembers. i.e It has to load balance between `http://example1.com/b/c/d` and `http://example2.com/b/c/d`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Always match slashes with the target:

```
ProxyPass /a/b/ balancer://mycluster/
```

If the target is balancer://mycluster you always need to add a trailing slash because it is really balancer://mycluster/ and if that is your target you need to add a trailing slash in the origin too, therefore ProxyPass /a/b/ . If you don't, you will have issues sening incorrect uri to the backend.